# Method Syntax in LINQ: try to use variables in a long query

Tags: linq

LINQ newbie here.

I have a long LINQ query, called it MYLONGQUERY, that returns a collection of certain class instances. If the list is not empty, I want to return a property (MYPROPERTY) of the first instance; otherwise it returns some default value (DEFAULTPROPERTY). So the query looks like this

(0 != MYLONGQUERY.count()) ? MYLONGQUERY.FirstOrDefault().MYPROPERTY: DEFAULTPROPERTY

This works fine. However, I don't like the fact that I have to repeat MYLONGQUERY before and after "?". I have been trying Let and Into, but have not been able to get those to work. And it has to be Method Syntax, not Query Syntax. Suggestions? Appreciate it.

Comment: Well blow me!  Its DefaultIfEmpty() not FirstOrDefault().  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355419(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Does it all have to be on one line?

Comment: What type of LINQ? (to SQL, to Entities, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the property first, then you can specify the default-value with [`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var prop = MYLONGQUERY
    .Select(x => x.MYPROPERTY)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(DEFAULTPROPERTY) // new default-value
    .First();                        // never exception
```